# serilog not logging with ubuntu ASP.NET Core

Tags: ubuntu, logging, .net-core, serilog

I'm using ubuntu 19.10 with .net core 3.1.
This is my first time using Serilog, with the following configuration:

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="3.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.sinks.file" Version="4.1.0" />

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Debug()
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .Enrich.FromLogContext().WriteTo.File("/tmp/log/LogFile.txt")
        .CreateLogger();

        Log.Information("Starting up the service");

        try{

            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

        }catch(Exception e)            
        {
            Log.Fatal(e, "There was a problem starting the service");
            return ;                
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            }).UseSerilog();
}}
```

I don't get any exception and the log file stays empty.
What am I missing ?

Thanks for your help..

Comment: Did you enable SelfLog to check for exceptions? https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics

Comment: yes, but I didn't get any output

Comment: also, if I'm adding .writeTo.Console()  to the same configuration it works, only writing to  file does not work.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right place for the output of `SelfLog`?

Comment: I have added :Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Debug.WriteLine(msg));
Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(Console.Error); so I should see the error in console/output window?

Comment: Does `Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Console.WriteLine(msg));` make any difference?

Comment: no, I still dont get any output

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data folder-that-is-the-app
sudo chown -R www-data folder-that-is-the-app
```

did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a file privilege issue , if I run "**sudo** dotnet run" then it works.I dont know why I didn't get any exception from Serilog that indicates that this is the issue.